# Mass replace drive letter on symlinks?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, find-and-replace

A drive letter changed (and I need to keep that change).  I had used Link Shell Extension to relocate many things before this happened, so I now have a lot of symlinks pointing to locations at the old drive letter.

Shortcuts have been fixed, and I was able to fix nearly all registry entries. However, it seems like I may need to tackle my symlinks one at a time. This is tedious.

Is there an efficient way I can change the drive letter in the path on all affected symbolic links?

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: You could write a PowerShell script for it. If you `Get-Item` a symbolic link it's type is `SymbolicLink` and it has a `Target`. One downside is that `mklink` seems to be a builtin for `cmd` so you will have to call cmd or maybe a batch to run `mklink`. `Get-ChildItem` supports `-Recurse`.

Comment: I would prefer mklink because it can create relative links. Then you can add a second layer of indirection to forever avoid this problem in the future.